# Cannot use regular expression in hadoop in Linux command line

Tags: hdfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, glob, cloudera

I have a folder that contains a large number of subfolders that are dates from 2018. In my HDFS I have created a folder of just December dates (formatted 2018-12-) and I need to delete specifically days 21 - 25. I copied this folder from my HDFS to my docker container and used the command

```
rm -r *[21-25]
```

in the folder it worked as expected. But when I run this same command adapted to hdfs

```
hdfs dfs –rm -r /home/cloudera/logs/2018-Dec/*[21-25]
```

it gives me the error

> rm: `/home/cloudera/logs/2018-Dec/*[21-25]': No such file or directory."

If you need something to be explained in more detail leave a comment. I'm brand new to all of this and I don't 100% understand how to say some of these things.

Comment: Shell wildcards are not regular expressions. And `[21-25]` is not a regular expression that matches the numbers from 21-25. What you want is `2[1-5]`

Comment: Or use `{21..25}`

Comment: @barmer I tried the first one and that didn't work but the second one would work but is there a way to do it without listing all of them?

Comment: You're not listing all of them, just the beginning and end of the range.

Comment: Note that wildcards are expanded on the local system. If you're deleting something on a remote system, it won't work.

Comment: @barmer I got it I was using the local system to refer to hdfs also I implemented the 2[1 -5] thing that you showed me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of @Barmer. I was referring to my local systems base directory also I had to change the regular expression to 2[1-5]. So the command ended up being `hdfs dfs -rm -r /user/cloudera/logs/2018-Dec/*2[1-5]`.